# Как получить ссылку на AccessibilityService на MIUI?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service

Пишу автокликер. Спрашиваю на счет MIUI, потому что на эмуляторе двух других телефонов получал таким образом и вроде работало, но только не на MIUI. На Miui приходиться останавливать и включать сервис чтоб дало ссылку

```
class AutoClickService : AccessibilityService() {

    companion object {
        private var instance: AutoClickService? = null
            set(value) {
                field = value
                instanceCallback?.invoke(field)
            }
        private var instanceCallback: ((AutoClickService?) -> Unit)? = null
            set(value) {
                field = value
                value?.invoke(instance)
            }

        fun getService(stateCallback: ((AutoClickService?) -> Unit)?): AutoClickService? {
            if (instance != null) {
                return instance
            }
            instanceCallback = stateCallback
            return null
        }
    }
 override fun onServiceConnected() {
        super.onServiceConnected()
        instance = this
        wm = getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
        mRunnable = IntervalRunnable()

    }
    ...
}
//В фрагменте
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.startMulti.setOnClickListener {
            if(!viewModel.hasAccessibilityPermission()) {
                showPermissionDialog()
                //MultiWigetView(requireContext(), AutoClickService())
            } else {
                if(viewModel.clickerService != null) {
                    viewModel.clickerService!!.startUI()
                } else {
                    viewModel.getService()
                    if(viewModel.clickerService != null) {
                        viewModel.clickerService!!.startUI()
                    } else {
                        L.i("Увы ничего не получилось")
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```